# Running setup.py install for httptools ... error

Tags: python, windows-10, rasa

I was trying to install rasa in win10 but it always shows the error for httptools set-up

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\sandy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sandy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5y1502t_\\httptools\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sandy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5y1502t_\\httptools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dg9lglte\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Did you try "Check the logs for full command output." ?

Comment: The question lacks detail and it would be better if you'd shown some (any) research effort

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue in windows 10 and after research, i found its a python installation issue in windows 10.

steps to resolve the issue:

1. Please uninstall non-relavent python from windows 10.(else create python virtual environment).
2. Please install chocolatey in windows 10 using - https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation#installing-chocolatey link.
3. Open cmd as admin and run below with specific python version
   choco install python3 --version 3.6.5
   ref - https://chocolatey.org/packages/python3/3.6.5
4. Verify your environment variable have a new Python installation path.
5. open new cmd and type python and verify the version.
6. on cmd run - pip install rasa.

it's better to create a virtual environment and do development there and follow above steps.
Go to new folder and open cmd .

7. pip3 install -U pip virtualenv (folder name).
8. type -  .\venv\Scripts\activate.
9. pip install --upgrade pip.

Source - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: hey a tried as you said, when its 3step it gets error

Comment: can you post the error? Please try with a virtual environment.

Comment: im total new to this i dont even understand this is error it shows
Chocolatey installed 0/0 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: please run cmd as admin then only it will install the packages

Comment: can i know what is chocolatey is why should we have it if we need to install rasa ...what is the actual prb with installing httptools package....

Comment: i tried this too..choco upgrade python3 --version 3.6.5        still has a error            Chocolatey upgraded 1/2 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - python3 (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Comment: Can you please uninstall the previous version and try to install again with Chocolatey instead of upgrading the python.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on "after research, i found its a python installation issue in windows 10" - this is the relevant part. It's not clear why Chocolatey (rather than other of the many ways to install Python) is solving the issue

Comment: @Neil yes its a python installation issue in windows10 and you can try other approaches also. After struggling for a long time i tried a chocolatey approach and it worked.

Comment: @piyush Is there a particular thing you can point to which makes it clear it's a Python installation issue in Windows 10?